# VSTS Agent, Docker and Bash shell script trap SIGTERM

Tags: bash, shell, docker, azure-devops

I wrote a bash shell script to handle spinning up a VSTS agent, and winding it down.

VSTS agent has two scripts you can call, `./config.sh` which takes either your VSTS configuration options for creating an agent or `remove` for clearing the agent from VSTS. It also has `./run.sh` which clearly runs the VSTS agent to allow it start receiving jobs.

I've created this simple shell script to handle this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function shutdown() {
    ./config.sh remove
}

trap shutdown SIGTERM SIGINT

cd ./vsts
./config.sh "$@"
./run.sh
```

I run `docker stop agent` and then `docker logs {container_id}` and the output doesn't show that `./config.sh remove` was called.

Does the SIGTERM get transferred down into scripts below, is this because the I'm not handling terminating the `./run.sh`?

### Edit

There is a really good example of how to do this with vsts:

https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/blob/a8df52909d7a085fecb836252791495dd401232e/ubuntu/16.04/standard/Dockerfile

Comment: I'm am not using linux/mac private agent, but for windows private agent, both the config.cmd and run.cmd files are call other execute file.

Comment: There are many VSTS docker images here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/tree/b96c48e5643ef1d499eff4d3c98c465dab509148,

Comment: I’m will look into them, I’ve based mine off a java image, a) because I need java, b) I can’t get the image as small if I did it myself!

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT that repo is really really helpful!

Comment: Do you mean the issue has been solved with that example?

Comment: No, it hasn’t solved this question, it has given a different solution!